# Proof of limit and limit point

Tags: limits

Decide whether or not the following functions have a limit at the indicated point:
$(a)\  f(x) = x^
3 + 3$ at the point $x = 3$

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=x^3+3$? If so, enclose your math in "$" and use "^" for exponentiation, and it will be formatted for you.

Comment: Decide whether or not the following functions have a limit at the indicated point:
(a) f(x) = x^3 + 3 at the point x = 3.

Comment: @user135855 You already indicated that under the question body.  It's better if you use $\LaTeX$.  See the [tutorial to learn how to use it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: what about 1/over x^2  is there a way to go around the not defined.

Answer (score 2):

First, assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  It is true that since $f(x) = x^3 + 3$ is a polynomial, it's continuous everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is continuous at every point $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which implies that $f$ is continuous at $x = 3$.  Thus, $f$ has a limit at $x = 3$.

In fact, $\lim\limits_{x \to 3} (x^3 + 3) = (3)^3 + 3 = 30$ and $f(3) = (3)^3 + 3 = 30$ .

Comment: 30 factorial :)

Comment: You mean 30"exclamation mark!".  Very funny joke

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)$ is a polynomial, it is continuous everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$, it has a limit at any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So, to calculate $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x)$, simply evaluate $f(x)$ at $x = a$.

Answer (score 1):

We will use the definition of a limit existing at a cluster point $c$. That is let f be a function defined on $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $c$ be a cluster point in $A$. Then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$ exists if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

In this case lets try to prove this. We see that at $x=3$ then $f(3)=27+3=30$. We will try to prove that $L=30$ We see that $|f(x)-L|=|x^3+3-30|=|x^3-27|=|x-3||x^2+3x+9|\leq|x-3|(|x|^2+3|x|+9)$. Lets try to bound this. Suppose that $|x-3|<2\implies 1<x<5\implies 1<x^2<25$ and $3|x|+9<3*5+9=24$. Thus $(|x|^2+3|x|+9)<(25+24)=49$.Therefore we will use $\frac{\epsilon}{49}$.

Proof:
Let $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a $\delta=min\{2,\frac{\epsilon}{49}\}$ and $0<|x-3|<\delta$. Then $|f(x)-L|=|x^3+3-30|=|x^3-27|=|x-3||x^2+3x+9|\leq|x-3|(|x|^2+3|x|+9)<49*\frac{\epsilon}{49}=\epsilon$. Thus the limit at $x=3$ exists.